# How to create external table for data in azure blob storage

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I'm trying to create an external table for data in Azure blob,
and I have used the flow script

```
create table [Sales].Currency
(
    [CurrencyCode] [nchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL  
)
with
(
    Location = '/samplefile/',
    data_source=currenytable,
    file_format=uncompressedData,
    reject_type=value,
    reject_value=0
);
```

when I execute this code I get the following error
Parse error at line: 10, column: 13: Incorrect syntax near ''/samplefile/''.
how to resolve this one thank you 
Note: I have successfully created all prior things for creating the external table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not as simple as a missing "EXTERNAL" statement.

You have:

```
create table [Sales].Currency
```

and it should be:

```
create EXTERNAL table [Sales].Currency
```